# What does $\delta_n$ refer to in "distribution of $T_k$", when defining mean recurrence time?

Tags: markov-chains

What does $\delta_n$ refer to in "distribution of $T_k$", when defining mean recurrence time?

Particularly

$$T_k:= \inf \{ n \geq 1: f_n=k\}$$

then my notes say:

$$\mathbb{P}(f_n=k, f_{n-1} \not=k, ..., f_1 \not=k | f_0=k)= f_{kk}^{(n)}$$

and that the distribution of $T_k$ is

$$\mathbb{P}_{T_k} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{kk}^{(n)} \delta_n$$

Is this some "standard" $\delta$?

Comment: @kimchilover What does that mean?

Comment: @kimchi Where do those sets come from?

Comment: @kimchilover I think I need an example to get this. E.g. to have some $k$ and then compute the first few terms of the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_n$ is a standard notation for the probability distribution that puts all its mass at the point $n$.

So your second displayed formula implies that $P(T_k=n) = f_{kk}^{(n)}$.

Comment: Shouldn't $\delta_n$ signify "value" by definition of probability distribution. Since $f_{kk}^{(n)}$ is the probability of that value, then what's the value?